# Multiple Library and include files Error after the Update of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I uninstall my old version of xcode then I installed the new version xcode 4.6. On the old Xcode version 4.5 my project compiled well and normally. But after the update, I get errors in my libraries:

```
 /client/iOS/Additions/Toast+UIView.h:31:9: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found

/client/iOS/AppDelegate.h:10:9: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found

/client/iOS/Additions/OrderedDictionary.h:26:9: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found

/client/iOS/main.m:9:9: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found

/client/iOS/Additions/TSXAdditions.h:10:9: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found

/client/iOS/Controllers/EditorBaseController.h:11:9: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found

/client/iOS/Misc/Reachability.m:48:9: 'sys/socket.h' file not found
```

How can I fix it??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the contents in the `build phases->Link binary with Libraries` and add them again

[image]